# Want to run asp.net 4 website on Ubuntu. Is it this simple?

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net, apt, mono

Hello I'm a Windows guy and would like to build a small, portable, mini ITX web servers with free software.

My application is ready. It's ASP.NET 4.0 connected to MySql 5. It runs on my Windows machine no problem, now I want to put it in a Linux box. I have previously ran some php websites in Ubuntu since apt-get install is very nice and easy, but I must say I'm still a Linux n00b.

I have Ubuntu 10.10 64 server.

Would it be as simple as:

1. apt-get install apache2
2. apt-get install mysql5
3. apt-get mono something
4. copy-paste the website files, done.

Is it this simple? Or are there complexities involved in step 3?

Oh and I assume i'll have to replace my MySql Connector/NET (MySql.Data.dll inside the bin folder) with a Mono version, right?

Comment: Are these going to be something that you are distributing a lot of?  If so, you need to consider maintenance and software upgrades, which are more important then the initial install.

Comment: @devicenull: not really a lot, and upgrades won't be frequent (if any). And in case of an upgrade, most probably, it will be a "packaged" upgrade. It's not a huge application anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it this simple? Or are there
>   complexities involved in step 3?

Ubuntu 10.10 contains mono 2.6.7 which doesn't support ASP.NET 4.0. You will have to build newer version of mono from source or tarballs using [parallel mono environment](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments). Try to look at [these](http://blog.ruski.co.za/post/2009/10/14/Mono-Compile-Install-Script.aspx) [two](http://nikola.plejic.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-on-ubuntu-linux-mono-nginx-mysql/) articles which should guide you to set up newer version of mono on your Ubuntu.

> Oh and I assume i'll have to replace
>   my MySql Connector/NET (MySql.Data.dll
>   inside the bin folder) with a Mono
>   version, right?

Yes, I think there is a special version for mono.